# Apache Tomcat : How to check the JVM argument set in Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat8, jvm-arguments

What is the way to check the JVM arguments in Apache Tomcat Server running on Unix machine.

Comment: `System.getProperty()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .........                                                                          where do we need to execute the command ?   Do we have any command which we can run on console to get all the JVM Arguments parameters values like heap size..GC algorithms...